# Using realloc with fails after certain size

Tags: c, exception, memory, dynamic, realloc

I am new to C, and I am trying to solve a coding excercise to practice.

In this particular method, I recevive as parameter a `char** s`which always contains 5 strings which I have to process and convert into just one, that is the return value of the method.

Given that there is no way to know how long the final string will be, my idea was to use `realloc` once I knew the length of each particular string in the array. However, even though it works for a couple of times, after some iterations (In a test case I run, for example it works until size = 43), it suddenly fails with `realloc(): invalid next size`.

I've searched all around and could not figure out what is that I am doing wrong. Could you please help me figure it out?

```c
char* process(char** s) {
    size_t size = 0, last = 0;
    char *result, *word, c;
    char *temp = NULL;
    result = malloc(1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        word = s[i];
        size += strlen(word);
        temp = realloc(result, size + 1);
        if (!temp){
            printf("Failed Reallocating");
            free(result);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else result = temp;
        for (size_t j = last; j < last + size; j++)
        {
            c = word[j - last];
            result[j] = isalpha(c) ? change_char(c) : c;
        }
        last += strlen(word);        
    }
    result[size] = '\0';
    return result;    
}
```

Comment: `j < last + size` is wrong. `last` is a position in the result being built, and `size` is the total current size of the `result` buffer, excluding space for a terminating null character. `last + size` is beyond the end of the buffer. In the future, always include a [mre] in requests for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing past the memory size you (re)allocated.
`temp = realloc(result, size + 1);` means you allocated *size+1* chars.

but in the inner loop `for (size_t j = last; j < last + size; j++)` the *j* goes all the way to *last+size-1* which is guaranteed to be past *size+1* and then you write `result[j] = isalpha(c) ? change_char(c) : c;` so you write past the memory you allocated, overwriting other data, including the meta-data *realloc* uses to keep track of what is allocated and what is free. Thus it will fail with an almost random error the next time you attempt to reallocate.

---

The fix is very simple, however. Iterate just up to the new size you allocated, `for (size_t j = last; j < size; j++)` and it will all work as expected.